# How to add successfully pcl library to a qt project with qmake

Tags: c++, qt, qmake, point-cloud-library

i am trying to include pcl library to my qt application project using qmake. I found some similar questions, however none of the answers help to solve my problem.

I have tried to add to the .pro file the paths from pcl lib as well as the 3rd party libraries which are used by pcl. Here is the include lines of my .pro file.

```
win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -LD:/Libraries/PCL_1.6.0/lib
win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -LD:/Libraries/PCL_1.6.0/3rdParty/Eigen/bin
win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -LD:/Libraries/PCL_1.6.0/3rdParty/Boost/lib

INCLUDEPATH +=  D:/Libraries/PCL_1.6.0/include/pcl-1.6
DEPENDPATH += D:/Libraries/PCL_1.6.0/include/pcl-1.6

INCLUDEPATH +=  D:/Libraries/PCL_1.6.0/3rdParty/Eigen/include
DEPENDPATH += D:/Libraries/PCL_1.6.0/3rdParty/Eigen/include

INCLUDEPATH +=  D:/Libraries/PCL_1.6.0/3rdParty/Boost/include
DEPENDPATH += D:/Libraries/PCL_1.6.0/3rdParty/Boost/include
```

After that, i am just trying put this include to one of my files:

```
include pcl/io/pcd_io.h
```

And these are the errors i am getting back:

> D:\Libraries\PCL_1.6.0\3rdParty\Eigen\include\Eigen\src\Core\products\GeneralBlockPanelKernel.h:604: error: unable to find string literal operator 'operator""X' with 'const char [2]', 'long long unsigned int' arguments
>    EIGEN_ASM_COMMENT("mybegin2");
>
> D:\Libraries\PCL_1.6.0\3rdParty\Eigen\include\Eigen\src\Core\products\GeneralBlockPanelKernel.h:640: error: unable to find string literal operator 'operator""X' with 'const char [2]', 'long long unsigned int' arguments
>    EIGEN_ASM_COMMENT("myend");
>
> D:\Libraries\PCL_1.6.0\3rdParty\Eigen\include\Eigen\src\Core\products\GeneralBlockPanelKernel.h:644: error: unable to find string literal operator 'operator""X' with 'const char [2]', 'long long unsigned int' arguments
>    EIGEN_ASM_COMMENT("mybegin4");

Can you please help me to solve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to use `CMake`. See the links below:

- These are two examples provided by PointCloudLibrary with `CMake`: [qt_colorize_cloud](https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/tree/master/doc/tutorials/content/sources/qt_colorize_cloud) and [qt_visualizer](https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/tree/master/doc/tutorials/content/sources/qt_visualizer).
- [Here](http://www.pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/qt_visualizer.php#qt-configuration) is the explanation for the configuration in `Qt`.

The `CMakeList.txt` is as follows:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.11)

project(pcl_visualizer)

# init_qt: Let's do the CMake job for us
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON) # For meta object compiler
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON) # Resource files
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON) # UI files

# Find includes in corresponding build directories
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

# Find the QtWidgets library
find_package(Qt5 REQUIRED Widgets)

find_package(VTK REQUIRED)
find_package(PCL 1.7.1 REQUIRED)

# Fix a compilation bug under ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial)
list(REMOVE_ITEM PCL_LIBRARIES "vtkproj4")

include_directories(${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_definitions(${PCL_DEFINITIONS})

set(project_SOURCES main.cpp pclviewer.cpp)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${project_SOURCES})

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${PCL_LIBRARIES} Qt5::Widgets)
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your information. However, i would like to import - configure pcl with qmake, because my existing application is using qmake. Do you know how if there is a way to do this?

Comment: With your current config, try to build with c++03 not with c++11 or above.

Comment: unfortunately, i got back the same error... thanks for the support

Comment: You're welcome. I think that there is another way to fix your issue, but a bit harder. 
Try find the definition of the `Macro` named `EIGEN_ASM_COMMENT` and add a space before the `X` which made the issue. Tell me if there is change.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, i try to find this macro and make the suggested modification